# How to highlight an entire route or way on an online map?

Tags: google-maps

For brevity, I'll write [throughfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoroughfare) instead of 'route', because I ask NOT only about vehicular roads, but also nature paths, trails, waterways, etc...

On Google Maps, how can I highlight the entirety of a throughfare (eg the Bruce Trail in Ontario, Canada)? For example, I wish to thicken the length and width of its depiction on the map, and to intensify its colour. To wit, I seek something like this:

[image: map from Toronto Hiking].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make your own custom map:

Go into [Google MyMaps](https://www.google.com/mymaps),

Click Create new map.

This opens a new map-editing window.

Use the Draw a Line tool   (under the search bar, looks a bit like a share-icon), to draw either just a line, or a driving, walking or biking route.   Note that your map can have one or more lines in it.   Finish off each line by double-clicking on the final point.

Then in the components list on the left of the screen, hover your mouse over a line:  this brings up a small paint-bucket icon to the right side of the line-name.   Click this icon, and you have options to choose the colour and thickness.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please clarify 'Go into maps'? Are you referring to Google Maps or Windows 8.1?

Comment: Google Maps - I've added a clarification tot he answer now.

Comment: I don't see a 'My Maps' option, even though I'm logged in. I tried clicking in the search bar as described, and also exploring the menu. But in any case, if I want to highlight, say, US-20 on a US map, would I manually need to draw each segment, coast to coast? I don't think this is a solution.

Comment: I've updated the answer for recent changes to Google's interface.   I agree that having to draw each segment manually is tedious - but I don't see it as any more tedious than having to pick out specific sections of existing roads.   And the original question includes a requirement non-road routes too, so these would always have to be manually drawn-in.