# How to show/share only one route on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I want to share a route between two places with some people, the plan being that we meet and follow this route together.

The new Google Maps has a (normally) nice feature that by default shows you several routes so you can choose one. When I've chosen my route, **how do I hide the others**?

I want to choose a route and send it (ideally with a live link), without provoking confusion or unnecessary debate by sending several options. But even when I select one route and go into step-by-step directions, the alternatives are still visible.

How do I show only my chosen route?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creating a custom map as per [MaryC's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/79784/45078) is good if you want something you save permanently or embed and don't mind going through a multi-step process with a different UI to get there.

I also found a **quick and  easy alternative** that uses only the regular Google Maps 'directions' UI.

Basically you just **drag part of the *path* then drop it where it was**:

1. Set up directions as normal, hover over part of the **path** of the route you want:

[image]

2. **Drag, then drop it right where it was.** You've now got only one route - and the URL of the page has auto-updated to point to this one route (you can also adjust the route if you want).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom map.   There are directions for doing this in the new Google Maps in the answers here:   [How to highlight an entire route or way on an online map?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79123/how-to-highlight-an-entire-route-or-way-on-an-online-map)

Once your custom maps is created, use the Share link to see the options for sharing it, or use the embed option if you want to put it into a website.