# Possible to add multiple markers to a map and share a link in Google Maps anonymously?

Tags: google-maps

Say, I go to http://maps.google.com (which these days redirects to https://www.google.com/maps) in my web browser. I can use the Search, and when my address is found, a (red) marker is added on the map. I can then copy this link and send it to someone else - and this works "anonymously" (that is, I don't have to be logged in to Google to do this). When the link is then opened, the marker is there.

How would I go about adding a second marker on the map like this? If I do another search, and a location is found, then the previous marker is deleted, and a new marker added at the new location - the link then changes to point to the newly added location, without reference to the old one.

I guess one way to do it would be to make a "custom map", as per the answer in [How to highlight an entire route or way on an online map?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79123/how-to-highlight-an-entire-route-or-way-on-an-online-map/79151#79151) - but requires that you are logged in with your Google account.

So how could I add multiple markers anonymously, and generate a shareable link to a map containing all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to [Google My Maps](https://google.com/mymaps), and click the Create a New Map button.   Use the map-making tool to add as many markers as you want. Then click the Share button in the left-hand panel.

[image]

That gives you a link that can be shared, as well as options to share it via Twitter, et al.

The map which is opened with the link doesn't say who the map owner is.